# Creating an array for a object in android game development

Tags: android

my game is basically a ninja that dodges throwing stars coming in from the right of the screen, however i want to create an array of different throwing stars that appear from the right. I have got one star coming in from the right at random intervals but would like more variety.

Question:
so my question is what could i add into my existing code to make random throwing objects appear from the right of the screen?

so far my code looks like this:

```
package com.example.game02;

import java.util.Random;

public class Star {

Random random = new Random();

public int x,y ;

public Star()
    {
        x = 32;
        y = random.nextInt(World.WORLD_HEIGHT -10);

    }

public void advance()
    {
        x = x -1 ;
    }

}
```

Comment: .... and the question is ?

Comment: sorry just edited my post, aha just realised :P

Comment: Random how? What do you want to be random?

Comment: Sorry im really bad at this lol, basically how do i make an array so different objects appear from the right of the screen because right now i got one star working but i would like another type of star to appear if that makes sense :/